# JPA returned object throwing Internal server error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jax-rs

I am building API using JAX-RS and MySql database (JPA).
I have following method which is validating username and password and creating a token for the session:

```
public Customer validateCustomer(Customer customer) {

    //get the customer from the database
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c from Customer c WHERE c.login = :username");
    q.setParameter("username", customer.getLogin());
    List<Customer> results = q.getResultList();
    
    //check if user exsists
    if(!results.isEmpty()){
       Customer fromDb = results.get(0);

       //check if user provided correct password
       if (!fromDb.getPassword().equals(customer.getPassword())) {
           return null;
       } else {
           //create the session token and save it to the database
           Random random = new SecureRandom();
           String token = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
           tx.begin();
           int executeUpdate = em.createQuery("UPDATE Customer c SET c.token = :token WHERE c.id = :id")
                   .setParameter("token", token)
                   .setParameter("id", fromDb.getId())
                   .executeUpdate();
           tx.commit();
           em.close();

           //update previously pulled customer with the token
           fromDb.setToken(token);

           //return the customer
           return fromDb;
       }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method is called and consumed by:

```
public Response login (Customer customer){
    Customer c = customerService.validateCustomer(customer);
    if (c != null){
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(c).build();
        //System.out.println(c);
    } else {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity("Incorrect username or password.").build();
    }
}
```

My problem is that Whenever a correct login is provided and I am returning my

> return fromDb;

I am getting internal server error 500 in my browser:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /api/users/login. Reason:
>
> Internal Server Error
>
> Powered by Jetty://

However an error only ocures when I am returning original Customer from the database. If I build new Customer object from the very same object returned from the database and return it it is working just fine.

```
Customer c = new Customer();
           c.setEmail(fromDb.getEmail());
           c.setLogin(fromDb.getLogin());
           c.setToken(token);
           c.setId(fromDb.getId());
```

Returning c instead of fromDb works fine.

Is there any reason why the object from database could return different results than the object built of it?

Server log when returning fromDB (getting error):

```
 INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)  
 INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20  
 INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true  
 INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]  
 INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}  
 INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  
 INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory  
 INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
 INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update  
 INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata  
 INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [balance, name, id, accnumber, sortcode]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [password, city, street, county, name, id, login, email, token]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer_account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [account_id, customer_id]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067]  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067, account_id]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.hibernate_sequences  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [sequence_next_hi_value, sequence_name]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: []  
 INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete  
 WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (Bank) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'  
 INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)  
 INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20  
 INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true  
 INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]  
 INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}  
 INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  
 INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory  
 INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
 INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update  
 INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata  
 INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [balance, name, id, accnumber, sortcode]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [password, city, street, county, name, id, login, email, token]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer_account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [account_id, customer_id]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067]  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067, account_id]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.hibernate_sequences  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [sequence_next_hi_value, sequence_name]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: []  
 INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete  
 WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (Bank) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'  
 com.mycompany.bank.model.Customer@769f10ad  
 Returning: com.mycompany.bank.model.Customer@e501b7e
```

Error log when returning c (no error)

```
 INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)  
 INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20  
 INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true  
 INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]  
 INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}  
 INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  
 INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory  
 INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
 INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update  
 INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata  
 INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [balance, name, id, accnumber, sortcode]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [password, city, street, county, name, id, login, email, token]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer_account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [account_id, customer_id]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067]  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067, account_id]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.hibernate_sequences  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [sequence_next_hi_value, sequence_name]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: []  
 INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete  
 WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (Bank) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'  
 INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)  
 INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20  
 INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true  
 INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]  
 INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}  
 INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  
 INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory  
 INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
 INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update  
 INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata  
 INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [balance, name, id, accnumber, sortcode]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [password, city, street, county, name, id, login, email, token]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer_account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [account_id, customer_id]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067]  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067, account_id]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.hibernate_sequences  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [sequence_next_hi_value, sequence_name]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: []  
 INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete  
 WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (Bank) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'  
 com.mycompany.bank.model.Customer@455917ff  
 Returning: com.mycompany.bank.model.Customer@302ab24b  
 INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)  
 INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20  
 INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true  
 INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]  
 INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}  
 INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  
 INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory  
 INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
 INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update  
 INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata  
 INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [balance, name, id, accnumber, sortcode]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [password, city, street, county, name, id, login, email, token]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer_account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [account_id, customer_id]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067]  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067, account_id]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.hibernate_sequences  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [sequence_next_hi_value, sequence_name]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: []  
 INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete  
 WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (Bank) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'  
 INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)  
 INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20  
 INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true  
 INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]  
 INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}  
 INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  
 INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory  
 INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
 INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update  
 INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata  
 INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [balance, name, id, accnumber, sortcode]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [password, city, street, county, name, id, login, email, token]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.customer_account  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [account_id, customer_id]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067]  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk70eacecc22b4f18d, fk70eacecc3a281067, account_id]  
 INFO: HHH000261: Table found: test.hibernate_sequences  
 INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [sequence_next_hi_value, sequence_name]  
 INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []  
 INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: []  
 INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete  
 WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (Bank) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
```

Comment: Do you have server side logging turned on for your App Server?  Could you post the stack trace there?

Comment: I am just thinking if the reason for above can be that the object retrieved from the database is not recognized by my $.ajax as a JSON. From my understanding    "@XmlRootElement" in my Customer class is responsible for 'casting' my Customers to XML and in the same time JSON.Maybe an object received from Database is not going through the same route and therefore    "@XmlRootElement" is not being applied to my object. Is that possible, and if so any idea how to work this around without creating new object and applying all attributes from one to another?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your query is not ok: you can't use aliases during update. Try `em.createQuery("UPDATE Customer SET token = :token WHERE id = :id")`

Comment: I have corrected my query but it didn't affect the results. However, thank you for your feedback, I am always happy to learn something from more experienced users. It is my first project using JPA (college project).

Comment: Please try to find application logs to check what is the error.